# pass an integer to Broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I have a service that subscribes from the server by Mqtt client. when arrived a message I do broadcast message and topic. In my fragment I declare a broadcast receiver like this:

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver mChatReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    int areaCode;

    private BroadcastReceiver init(int areaCode) {
        Log.i("====>", "init: BroadcastReceiver ");
        this.areaCode = areaCode;
        return this;
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.i("====>", "onReceive: BroadcastReceiver ");
        //do sth

    }
}.init(areaCode);
```

but `init(areaCode)` do not work and in original areaCode is for example 2 but I did not get 2 in `private BroadcastReceiver init(int areaCode)`. I got 0.

how can I pass an integer out of `private final BroadcastReceiver mChatReceiver` class to this class?

Answer (score 1):

Say you are registering for some custom `IntentFilter` like this:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.packageName.ACTION_SEND_INTEGER");
```

Register receiver like this:

```
your_context.registerReceiver(mChatReceiver,filter);
```

Trigger your broadcast receiver like this and send an integer:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.packageName.ACTION_SEND_INTEGER");
        intent.putExtra("your_value",123);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: I do sendBroadcast from my service, where i do not access to my data till i send it by putExta. my integer is dynamic

Comment: @sayreskabir Sorry I did not get your comment.Could you please re-phrase again ?